# MaterializeCSS Select not POSTing with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, post, materialize

I have created a form to submit vehicle details and when I've gone to test the form, the data from the SELECT options is not pulling through but everything else is, for example the input boxes are pulling the data through, so when I check the data by doing;

```
echo $_POST['up_model'];
```

Nothing is being displayed and i'm using MaterializeCSS as the framework

**HTML**

```
                                            <form action="" method="POST">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="up_vehicleID" value="<?= $vehRow['veh_id']; ?>">

                                                <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col s12">
                                                    <ul class="tabs">
                                                        <li class="tab col s4"><a class="active" href="#veh_details<?= $vehRow['veh_id']; ?>">Vehicle Details</a></li>
                                                        <li class="tab col s4"><a href="#veh_order<?= $vehRow['veh_id']; ?>">Order Details</a></li>
                                                        <li class="tab col s4"><a href="#veh_delivery<?= $vehRow['veh_id']; ?>">Delivery Details</a></li>
                                                        <!-- <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li> -->
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>

                                                <div id="veh_details<?= $vehRow['veh_id']; ?>" class="col s12">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                                                            <select name="up_model">
                                                                <option value="<?= $vehRow['veh_model']; ?>"><?= $vehRow['veh_model']; ?></option>
                                                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                                                <option value="ZS">ZS</option>
                                                                <option value="ZS EV">ZS EV</option>
                                                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                                                <option value="HS">HS</option>
                                                                <option value="HS PHEV">HS PHEV</option>
                                                            </select>
                                                            <label>Model</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                                                            <select name="up_spec">
                                                                <option value="" disabled selected><?= $vehRow['veh_spec']; ?></option>
                                                                <option value="Explore">Explore</option>
                                                                <option value="Excite">Excite</option>
                                                                <option value="Exclusive">Exclusive</option>
                                                            </select>
                                                            <label>Derivative</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                                                            <select name="up_trans">
                                                                <option value="" disabled selected><?= $vehRow['veh_trans']; ?></option>
                                                                <option value="MT">MT</option>
                                                                <option value="AT">AT</option>
                                                            </select>
                                                            <label>Transmission</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                                                            <input id="up_colour" value="<?= $vehRow['veh_colour']; ?>" name="up_colour" type="text" class="validate">
                                                            <label for="up_colour">Colour</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                                                            <select name="up_fuel">
                                                                <option value="" disabled selected><?= ucfirst($vehRow['veh_fuel']); ?></option>
                                                                <option value="Petrol">Petrol</option>
                                                                <option value="Diesel">Diesel</option>
                                                                <option value="Hybrid">Hybrid</option>
                                                                <option value="Electric">Electric</option>
                                                            </select>
                                                            <label>Fuel Type</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                                                            <select name="up_engine">
                                                                <option value="" disabled selected><?= $vehRow['veh_engine']; ?></option>
                                                                <option value="1.0">1.0</option>
                                                                <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
                                                                <option value="Electric">Electric</option>
                                                            </select>
                                                            <label>Engine Size</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                                                            <select name="up_interior">
                                                                <option value="" disabled selected><?= $vehRow['veh_interior']; ?></option>
                                                                <option value="Black - Leather">Black - Leather</option>
                                                                <option value="Red - Leather">Red - Leather</option>
                                                                <option value="Black - Cloth">Black - Cloth</option>
                                                            </select>
                                                            <label>Interior Trim</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div id="veh_order<?= $vehRow['veh_id']; ?>" class="col s12">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                                                            <input value="<?= $vehRow['veh_vinnum']; ?>" name="up_vin" id="up_vin" type="text" class="validate">
                                                            <label for="up_vin">Vin Number</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                                                            <input id="up_ordernum" value="<?= $vehRow['veh_ordernum']; ?>" name="up_ordernum" type="text" class="validate">
                                                            <label for="up_ordernum">Order Number</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                                                            <input value="<?= $vehRow['veh_registration']; ?>" id="up_reg" name="up_reg" type="text" class="validate">
                                                            <label for="up_reg">Registration</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                                                            <input id="up_stocknum" value="<?= $vehRow['veh_stocknum']; ?>" name="up_stocknum" type="text" class="validate">
                                                            <label for="up_stocknum">Stock Number</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                                                            <input value="<?= $vehRow['veh_offplan']; ?>" id="up_offplan" name="up_offplan" type="date" class="validate">
                                                            <label for="up_offplan">Date off Plan</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div id="veh_delivery<?= $vehRow['veh_id']; ?>" class="col s12">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                                                            <input value="<?= $vehRow['veh_delivery']; ?>" id="up_delivery" name="up_delivery" type="date" class="validate">
                                                            <label for="up_delivery">Delivery Date</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                                                            <select name="up_stockstatus">
                                                                <option value="" disabled selected><?= $vehRow['veh_stockStatus']; ?></option>
                                                                <option value="in stock">In Stock</option>
                                                                <option value="not in stock">Not in Stock</option>
                                                            </select>
                                                            <label>Stock Status</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                                                            <input id="up_status" value="<?= $vehRow['veh_status']; ?>" name="up_status" type="text" class="validate">
                                                            <label for="up_status">Status</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- <div id="test4" class="col s12">

                                                </div> -->
                                                </div>




                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col s12 m6 offset-m6">
                                                        <button class="btn waves-effect blue right waves-light" type="submit" name="up_button">Save
                                                            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </form>
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['up_button'])) {
  echo "Model: ".$_POST['up_model'];
}
```

Comment: Is that field inside your form? Is there maybe another (hidden) input in your form with the same name?

Comment: Nope, as I have multiple select's and none of them submit any data

Comment: Your IF is validating `up_button` not `up_model`. To better debug use `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: Yes that is because it is a large form with over 15 different inputs so didn't want to post the entire form but yes I use the ```up_button``` to validate. I have tried ```var_dump``` and it returns NULL

Comment: I've now tried ```var_dump($_POST)``` and none of my select inputs are coming through but all my other inputs are

Comment: You need to include a field named `up_button` in your form. This is missing so your Model is not echoed.

Comment: I have, the button is in there but the form is quite long so hadn't posted it

Answer (score 2):

Please past your code completely, which is inside your `from` tag, but if I want to just look and your code right now, you are checking this condition `if (isset($_POST['up_button']))` but you do not send any input with this name so maybe you need to change this condition to this :

```php
if (isset($_POST['up_model'])) {
  echo "Model: ".$_POST['up_model'];
}
```

And if you want to look at all of your data that you send, you can do this

```php
print_r($_POST)
```

Comment: I've updated the questions with all the code